# Multiple colors in one cell while appending values with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to append values within a single cell by checking the values of other cells.  What I want to do next is change the font color of the value I am appending, and keep any existing font colors.  Ex:  Value of a1 is "".  I then append the value "abc " in green.  I then append the value "123 " in red.  I want the cell to show:

[(red)(green)]

["abc 123 "]

My code:

```
If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = "Control" Then
     bit_value = "(" & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value, Range("Output"), total_bits + 3, False) & ")" & high_low & "  "
     Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value & bit_value
End If
```

My Data:

```
504003  Control     2   11  55  12  21  00010001    01010101    00010010    00100001
504003  Control     2   11  55  12  20  00010001    01010101    00010010    00100000
```

**UPDATE:**
By utilizing Tim's code, I arrived at the changes below, and it does exactly what I needed.

```
bitColor = IIf(ActiveCell.Value = 0, RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(0, 0, 255))
If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = "Control" Then
     With Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7)
          bit_value = "(" & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(Active _
               Cell.Row, 5).Value,Range("Output"), total_bits + 3, False) & ")"
          AddValue Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7), bit_value, bitColor
     End With
End If
```

Comment: You're not using the `Characters` property correctly - here you need to specify a range of characters to work with (at least you should provide a start position). Might be easier just to call my Sub directly from your code e.g. `AddValue Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7), [your lookup value here], bitColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to add text to a cell without losing any existing formatting:

```
Sub Tester()
    With ActiveSheet
        AddValue .Range("A1"), "Hello", vbRed
        AddValue .Range("A1"), "Hello", vbGreen
        AddValue .Range("A1"), "Hello", vbBlue
    End With
End Sub


Sub AddValue(rngVal As Range, val, theColor As Long)
    Const SEP As String = " "
    Dim firstChar As Long, extra As Long

    firstChar = 1 + Len(rngVal.Value)
    extra = IIf(firstChar = 1, 0, 1)

    With rngVal
        .Characters(firstChar).Text = IIf(Len(rngVal.Value) > 0, SEP, "") & val
        .Characters(firstChar + extra, Len(val)).Font.Color = theColor
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** you only get up to 255 characters using this approach

Comment: Need a bit more help and can't get the formatting right in the comment.  Should I just update the question?

Comment: Yes - much better to update your question than to put code in comments: too difficult to read it there.

Comment: Works excellent by calling your Sub directly.  I don't see any significant loss of performance, even with a large set of data.  Thanks so much!